# Nativescript - app launch icon shapes on different devices

Tags: android, icons, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-cli

I used nativescript CLI "tns resources generate icons" command to generate my icons. Everything looks nice, but... not on all devices. When I installed my app on android emulator with this specification:

```
  Device: pixel_xl (Google)
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
  Based on: Android API 28 
  Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
```

my app icon looks strange. It seems all icons on this type of device are in circles. My icon is square shaped with background and it's scaled down and put inside this circle with white padding around (which is ugly).

How can I handle this? When I used another tool to generate circle icons everything looks nice, but in this case I have a circle icon on every device. I want a square - is there any chance to achieve this and at the same time have a circle icon on Android version, where all of icons are in circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the adaptive launch icon

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces adaptive launcher icons, which can display a variety of shapes across different device models. For example, an adaptive launcher icon can display a circular shape on one OEM device, and display a squircle on another device. Each device OEM provides a mask, which the system then uses to render all adaptive icons with the same shape. Adaptive launcher icons are also used in shortcuts, the Settings app, sharing dialogs, and the overview screen.

There is an open feature request at [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3697). If you are interested to use these icons for your app, nStudio had published a [blog post](https://nstudio.io/blog/adaptive-icons/) that might help you.